# Chart.js Line Chart x-Axes label rounding

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart made with chart.js show below :

[image]

Now, I want the x-Axes labels/Ticks in rounding figure like

0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let options = {
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 1
        }
    }]
  }
};
```

I haven't tested but it should work as per docs.